# Set WindowStartupLocation to the Margin.Top of Button1 of the main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a project where I have to add a small preview pane and a about box whenever a user is hovering the buttons on the main window.

For the examlpe: I have a window - preview.xaml, and my main window called MainWindow.xaml.

How do I set the preview windows bottom to appear on the top of button1 on the MainWindow?

I tried something like this without any luck:

```
public preview()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
   Top = mainWindow.button1.Margin.Top;
}
```

I hope my ramblings makes any sense...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A couple of questions: Where's the code that shows the preview? What value does `mainWindow.button1.Margin.Top` actually have? Where does your window actually appear in relation to where you want it to appear?

Comment: The code that shows the preview is during a MouseEnter event on the MainForm which is only: preview.show();. The preview window currently appear on the top, far to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `Left` and `Top` window properties to screen coordinates, button margins won't help here. Use `PointToScreen` function to obtain screen coordinates of your buttons:

```
    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = ((FrameworkElement)sender);
        // get screen coordinates of (0,0) point of button
        var location = control.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        var w = new preview()
        {
            WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.Manual,
            ShowActivated = false,
        };
        w.Top = location.Y - w.Height;
        w.Left = location.X + (control.ActualWidth - w.Width) / 2;
        w.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it the other way round. In your MainWindow where you open the preview-window do something like this:

```
PreviewWindow preview = new PreviewWindow
{
     Owner = this,
     WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual,
     Top = button1.Margin.Top
};
preview.Show();
```

If you want to reuse that window, you have to do a little logic around.

Comment: hmm, the window is still opening on the top of the screen far to the left. If I change 'Top = button1.Margin.Top' to 'Top = button1.Margin.Bottom' the window will slightly more to the right.

Comment: @RobinNilsson: Ah, I missed that point. You have to get the absolute screen coordinates. You can get the Screen-Coordinates with `PointToScreen(new Point(button.Margin.Left, button.Margin.Top));`